# How to prevent overlapping between dots on scatter plot via D3 and ensure that dots remain within chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, collision-detection

Problem Description:
I am building a scatter plot using D3.js within a React component. My objective is to display a set of data points (nodes) without them overlapping each other or overflowing outside the chart boundaries. I am using D3's force simulation to achieve this. However, I am encountering two issues:

1. The nodes are overlapping each other.
2. Some nodes are overflowing outside the chart boundaries.

I am basing my work off this observable: https://observablehq.com/@keckelt/collision-free-scatter-plot.

Attempted Solution:
I used D3's forceSimulation with forceX, forceY, and forceCollide to position the nodes and prevent overlap. However, the nodes still overlap and some even overflow the chart area.

Setting Up Scales:
Here's the useEffect hook where I set up the scales:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const [widthAdjusted, heightAdjusted] = getAdjustedWidth(width, height);

  const scaleX = scaleLinear()
    .domain([Math.min(...data.map(d => d.x)), Math.max(...data.map(d => d.x))])
    .nice()
    .range([0, widthAdjusted]);

  const scaleY = scaleLinear()
    .domain([Math.min(...data.map(d => d.y)), Math.max(...data.map(d => d.y))])
    .nice()
    .range([heightAdjusted, 0]);

  setScales({ scaleX, scaleY });
}, [data, width, height]);
```

Force Simulation:
The D3 force simulation setup in another useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!scales) return;

  const transformedData = data.map(d => ({
    ...d,
    x: scales.scaleX(d.x),
    y: scales.scaleY(d.y),
  }));

  const forceSimulation = d3.forceSimulation(transformedData)
    .force('x', d3.forceX(d => d.x).strength(0.1))
    .force('y', d3.forceY(d => d.y).strength(0.1))
    .force('collide', d3.forceCollide().radius(20).strength(1))
    .stop();

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    forceSimulation.tick();
  }

  const updatedData = forceSimulation.nodes().map(d => ({
    ...d,
    x: scales.scaleX.invert(d.x),
    y: scales.scaleY.invert(d.y),
  }));

  setNodes(updatedData);
}, [data, scales]);
```

How can I adjust my force simulation and scaling to ensure nodes don't overlap and stay within the chart boundaries?